# i want to change the size of font awesome icons in the mega menu of my wordpress website using custome css

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

i want to change the size of font awesome icons in the mega menu of my wordpress website using custome css as shown in this pic

[image]

i use inspect element of mozilla for finding css of my site. i found this

```
.mega-menu li.menu-item > a > .fa, .mega-menu li.menu-item > h5 > .fa
```

and

```
 #header .header-main .container #main-menu .mega-menu
```

What should i do now. Please help.

Comment: Why not just use the `fa-lg`, `fa-2x` etc helper classes included with FontAwesome? http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/. Even if you don't want to use those, all you have to do is set the `font-size` for the elements in the selectors you specify.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.mega-menu li.menu-item > a > .fa, .mega-menu li.menu-item > h5 > .fa
{
font-size:16px; //or the font size you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To increase the size of icons relative to its container, use `icon-large`, `icon-2x`, `icon-3x`, or `icon-4x`.

here are some examples

```
<p><i class="icon-camera-retro icon-large"></i> icon-camera-retro</p>
<p><i class="icon-camera-retro icon-2x"></i> icon-camera-retro</p>
<p><i class="icon-camera-retro icon-3x"></i> icon-camera-retro</p>
<p><i class="icon-camera-retro icon-4x"></i> icon-camera-retro</p>
```

Make sure you have sufficient line-height to contain your icon

in your case you would have to do

```
 <i class="fa fa-windows icon-large">WINDOWS</i>
```

or something like that (i don't use font awesome icons)

[Source](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/examples/)